# VC2010 implementation of std::is_base_of contains a bug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11, std

By C++11 standard `std::is_base_of<B, D>` must return true if D is derived from B or if both are the same non-union class. But in VC++ 2010 stl implementation template return true if the type B is a ONLY base class of the type D! Is it a bug ?

At http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982243(v=vs.100).aspx page in example section

```
std::is_base_of<base, base> == true
```

but this does not correspond VC++2010 STL implementation. Although it is consistent with the requirement of the C++11 standard. Where is a bug ?

Comment: Remember that C++11 is still quite new, and that lots of features in the standard haven't been implemented yet. Not even VC++2012 implements the full C++11 yet.

Comment: `std::is_base_of<base, base>::value` evaluates to `true` for me with VS2010 SP1 and VS2012.  May it's a pre-SP1 bug? (I have no easy means to test VS2010 without SP1). Can you post a compilable code that shows the problem?

Comment: Yes of course. `static_assert( is_base_of<int, int>::value, "Invalid std::is_base_or_same implementation");` is always error. My VS 2010 version is "10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`is_base_of<int, int>::value` evaluates to `false` (your comment indicates that this is the actual question you have) because `is_base_of<>::value` can evaluate to `true` only if the template parameters are class types. The C++11 standard's Table 51 - Type relationship predicates (C++ 20.9.6 "Relationships between types") defines `is_base_type<>` to evaluate to true if and only if (emphasis added):

> Base is a base class of Derived without regard to cv-qualifiers or Base and Derived are not unions and name the same **class type** without regard to cv-qualifiers

The C++11 standard even has the following as one of its examples (C++11 20.9.6/3):

> ```
> is_base_of<int, int>::value // false
> ```

Comment: +1 - Hah perfect, shows how a simple code example in the question could have cleared the whole matter.

Comment: Thank you, I lost sight of it for classes.